# Prime and Maximal Ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Consider $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Also let $p$ be a prime. Then we want to find all the prime and maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. The prime ideals are $(0), (p), (x)$ and $(ap + bx)$. Then we see that the last one contains all the previous ones making it a maximal ideal for $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. **Is this the correct way to think about it?**

Also, since $(ap + bx)$ is a maximal ideal this means that $R/$(ap + bx)$ is a field. **How can I see that this quotient is indeed a field?**

Finally, how could I find the same for $\mathbb{Q}$ and then for a generic $k$?

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not a PID,

Comment: No, your characterization of prime ideals is wrong. For one thing, you're saying all the maximal ideals are principal, which in a Noetherian ring would mean that all ideals are principal, but $\Bbb Z[x]$ is not a PID. There are other prime ideals like $(2, x+1)$.

Comment: In answer to your coat-tail question, for a field $k$, $k[x]$ is a principal ideal domain, and there the primes are exactly $\{0\}$ and $(f(x))$ where $f(x)$ is any polynomial irreducible over $k$. The nonzero prime ideals are the maximal ideals.

Comment: Could you make this more concrete for $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ or $\mathbb{R}[x]$. As for my characterization for prime ideals I mean it only for this case I don't see where I am wrong. It is indeed true that $(ap+bx)$ contains the others, right?